# How to remove duplicate nodes in linq to xml document

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

In the following XML there are 2 sets of nodes that have the same TxnID.  Using linq to XML how does one remove the duplicate PurchaseOrderRet nodes.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<QBPOSXML>
  <QBPOSXMLMsgsRs>
  <PurchaseOrderQueryRs>
      <PurchaseOrderRet>
        <TxnID>abc</TxnID>
      </PurchaseOrderRet>
    </PurchaseOrderQueryRs>
   <PurchaseOrderQueryRs>
      <PurchaseOrderRet>
        <TxnID>xyz</TxnID>
      </PurchaseOrderRet>
    </PurchaseOrderQueryRs>
  <PurchaseOrderQueryRs>
      <PurchaseOrderRet>
        <TxnID>abc</TxnID>
      </PurchaseOrderRet>
        <PurchaseOrderRet>
        <TxnID>def</TxnID>
      </PurchaseOrderRet>
      <PurchaseOrderRet>
        <TxnID>xyz</TxnID>
      </PurchaseOrderRet>
    </PurchaseOrderQueryRs>
  </QBPOSXMLMsgsRs>
</QBPOSXML>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this statement:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"mypath\MyFile.xml");
```

to load the XML into an `XDocument` object.

You can use `GroupBy` to identify duplicate `<TxnID>` elements. After applying the following operations onto `doc`:

```
 doc.Descendants("PurchaseOrderRet")
    .GroupBy(p => p.Element("TxnID").Value)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x => x.Skip(1).Remove());
```

`doc` holds the following XML:

```
- <QBPOSXML>
  - <QBPOSXMLMsgsRs>
    - <PurchaseOrderQueryRs>
      - <PurchaseOrderRet>
          <TxnID>abc</TxnID> 
        </PurchaseOrderRet>
      </PurchaseOrderQueryRs>
    - <PurchaseOrderQueryRs>
      - <PurchaseOrderRet>
          <TxnID>xyz</TxnID> 
        </PurchaseOrderRet>
      </PurchaseOrderQueryRs>
    - <PurchaseOrderQueryRs>
      - <PurchaseOrderRet>
          <TxnID>def</TxnID> 
        </PurchaseOrderRet>
      </PurchaseOrderQueryRs>
    </QBPOSXMLMsgsRs>
  </QBPOSXML>
```